# Why npm install is so slow on Windows 10?

Tags: javascript, windows, npm, node-modules

It takes around 30 minutes to install and run a pretty small project somehow.
It usually stuck at step `[WARNING] npm WARN prepare removing existing node_modules/ before installation`.
Then it stucks at step `[INFO] Running 'npm run build' in D:\Repositories\project\front`.

I've googled this problem a lot, but nothing helped.
But I do have some settings at my .npmrc file, such as `registry` specified, `strict-ssl=false` and auth with cert and key.

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/873#issuecomment-425272829) or [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1124472/why-is-linux-30x-faster-than-windows-10-in-copying-files) answer your question?

Comment: @icebp it might, but I am not able to change file system...

Comment: The difference you see comes from the fact that on Windows file accesses are a lot slower than on Linux. There's nothing you can do about that.